# Apache Spark - passing jdbc connection object to executors

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jdbc, apache-spark-sql-repartition

I am creating a jdbc object in spark driver and I am using that in executor to access the db. So my concern is that is it the same connection object or executors would get a copy of connection object so there would be separate connection per partition?

Comment: Did answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Scala - not that you state if pyspark, Java or Scala,

  - you can create an `Object` for a `ConnectionPool` as per link below;

    - this will be instantiated *for each* `Executor` and shared by `Cores` comprising that `Executor`. I.e. *not* as a Singleton for all foreachPartition.

      - Your concern / question is addressed in the previous bullet, i.e. their own Connections.

See https://medium.com/@ravishankar.nair/implementing-a-connectionpool-in-apache-sparks-foreachpartition-4add46dc8ae2. It's a good reference from medium.com.